# Move the x position of a button during runtime in win32 using C

Tags: c, winapi, button, move

I haven't been able to find much about this in my win32 book or using google.  I want to move the x position of a push button I created in a dialog window.  In a nutshell, I have 6 buttons and want to reposition them based on if I have to display 4, 5, or 6 buttons.

The goal is to send a message to a button during runtime and move it's x position.  I can find simple ways to update the buttons text field and color during runtime, but not position.

My button is...

```
#define IDC_PB_BUTTON_A
```

and created as this in a dialog window...

```
PUSHBUTTON    "A", IDC_PB_BUTTON_A, 4, 4, 30, 30, BS_MULTILINE
```

I would like to grab that first 4 value during runtime and move it over 10 units making it... where the x position value has changed from 4 to 14.

```
PUSHBUTTON    "A", IDC_PB_BUTTON_A, 14, 4, 30, 30, BS_MULTILINE
```

I was hoping I could do this with some sort of SendDlgItemMessage(), but can't find anything on the subject.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please stop editing the answer into your question. If it's sufficiently different to the current answer, post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API call to move a window is [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx)<sup>1</sup>. Make sure to pass `SWP_NOSIZE` so that the controls retain their initial size.

---

<sup>1</sup> *You could use [MoveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534.aspx) as well, but that requires that you pass in the new window size as well as the position. To retain the window size you'd have to call [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) first.*

Comment: Does SetWindowPos just move the actually dialog?  I'm trying to only move a certain push button inside of the dialog box and not the entire window.

Comment: @Yawn: I posted a link to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx), in the hope that I don't have to repeat it again. Guess I was wrong, so here it is again: *"Changes the [...] position [...] of a child [...] window."*

Comment: Yes I read the document, I just don't see where that grabs the button.  It seems to take two HWND values and not a button.

Comment: @Yawn: **Every** window is referenced through a `HWND`. There is no dedicated type to represent a button, edit, or listview control in the Windows API. This is a basic concept, explained in any Windows API programming book.

Comment: @yawn call `GetDlgItem` to obtain the window handle for one of your dialog's child windows